# ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache().get(imageUrl) returns different paths

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

1. Call to cache

   ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(cnt, imageUrl, new ImageLoadingListener()
2. `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/[package]/cache/40d1dxbmdamufgcs742bjraew` is created
3. `ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache().get(imageUrl)`  - returns `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/[package]/cache/40d1dxbmdamufgcs742bjraew` -> OK
4. reboot device
5. `ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache().get(imageUrl)`  - returns `/data/data/[package]/cache/40d1dxbmdamufgcs742bjraew` -> KO (THIS FOLDER IS CREATED BUT ITS" EMPTY)

Comment: can't understand your question and what you are trying to do? Using UIL?

Comment: downvoter, what's wrong?

Comment: The cache is a cache. It is cleared when the device reboots. it is used for temprorary data, e.g such data that can change during next app start. Maybe the SDCard was unavailable or had not enough space at the time it returned the phone's directory.

Comment: No with SD Card cache everything is OK

Comment: Check that SDcard is available when it returns the cache directory. But nevertheless you should not worry about losing cache data after reboot or just losing. From docs: "These files will be ones that get deleted first when the device runs low on storage."

Comment: As I said with cache everything is OK, problem that lib is looking for cache files in incorrect place/

Comment: What I mean is It must have changed the cache directory because the SDCard was unavailable when you launched the app and it switched to phone's one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to  **Doctoror Drive**

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core

/**
     * Returns application cache directory. Cache directory will be created on SD card
     * *("/Android/data/[app_package_name]/cache")* if card is mounted. Else - Android defines cache directory on
     * device's file system.
     * 
     * @param context Application context
     * @return Cache {@link File directory}
     */

```
public static File getCacheDirectory(Context context) {
        File appCacheDir = null;
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            appCacheDir = getExternalCacheDir(context);
        }
        if (appCacheDir == null) {
            appCacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        }
        return appCacheDir;
    }
```

Comment: I was facing the same problem  on some devices, thanks for pointing this out